# How to delete special char in C?

Tags: c, linux, string

There is a string

```
char *message = "hello#world#####.......";
```

How to delete all the "#" and return "helloworld" ?

In Ruby I can use gsub to deal with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, you have to do it yourself. For example:

```
#include <string.h>

char *remove_all(const char *source, char c)
{
    char *result = (char *) malloc(strlen(source) + 1);
    char *r = result;
    while (*source != '\0')
    {
        if (*source != c)
            *r++ = *source;
        source++;
    }

    *r = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

Note that in that implementation, the caller would have to free the result string.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a better algorithm to do this....no freeing is necessary - it's in-place.

```
char *remove_all(char *string, char c) 
{
   int idx = 0;
   char *beg = string;
   while(*string) {
      if (*string != c) 
         beg[idx++] = *string;
      ++string;
   }
   beg[idx] = 0;

   return beg;
}
```

Comment: Notice that the `char*` in the question is initialized to point to a string literal, which cannot safely be written to.  So yes, memory does need to be allocated to store the result.

Comment: That's actually something that doesn't hold, as my signature requires a char *, and not a const char *.  Although C lets you pass in string literals as char *'s...then again it assumes the end user knows what he's doing in the first place. But agreed - you can't write to string literals, at all.